# How to add a calculated field in the FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT Event

Tags: events, listener, symfony-forms, symfony

In  my listener I need to access my entity when in the `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event. In `POST_SET_DATA` this is no problem, just use `$event->getData();`.

So for the event listening to `POST_SET_DATA` I am fine with this code:

```
public function postSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $day = $event->getData();
    $total = $this->dayManager->calculateTotal($day); // Passing a Day object, yay!

    $form->get('total')->setData($total);
}
```

However in my method for the `PRE_SUBMIT` event.

*I need this function because on submitting, total is not calculated with the newly submitted data.*

```
public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // $day = $event->getData();
    // Raw array because $event->getData(); holds the old not updated Day object
    $day = $form->getData(); 

    // Ough! Had to create and call a seperate function on my dayManager that handles the raw event array
    $total = $this->dayManager->calculateTotalFromArray($event->getData());

    // Modify event data
    $data = $event->getData();

    // Ough(2)! Have to do nasty things to match the raw event array notation
    $totalArray = array( 
       'hour' => $total->format('G') . "", 
       'minute' => intval($total->format('i')) . ""
    );
    $data['total'] = $totalArray;
    $event->setData($data);
}
```

As you can see, it works. However this is such a hackish way, I do not believe the pro's do it this way. Two things that go wrong here:

- Cannot work with entity `Day` object in the `preSubmit` function
- Have to create the `calculateTotalFromArray` function in the `dayManager`
- Ugly code to match the raw event array in the `preSubmit` function

**So the main question:** how to get an updated `Day` object from the form in the `PRE_SUBMIT` form event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use** `SUBMIT` **instead of** `PRE_SUBMIT`

Don't worry, the form is not yet submitted, `SUBMIT` is executed right before `Form::submit`

**Why are you having this problem?**

All data in `PRE_SUBMIT` has not been normalized into your usual object...

If you'd like to learn more about the whole thing, please head to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Comment: Hi @galeaspablo, Thanks for your answer. I already figured out that I need to use ::SUBMIT, however you was first with the answer! So you get the credits ;-) I will add an answer below how I solved it in my code-base.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @galeaspablo for submitting the answer! However I add below my code how I solved my particular problem.

My goal was to show a calculated total field in a form. Nothing more. However in the `SUBMIT` event you cannot do a `$form->get('total')->setData($total);`. You will get a warning: `You cannot change the data of a submitted form.`

So altering a form after `PRE_SUBMIT` is not possible. But adding fields **is**..

My complete solution is as follows:

In the DayType formbuilder:

```
// Will add total field via subscriber
//->add('total', TimeType::class, ['mapped' => false])
```

In the event subscriber:

```
class CalculateDayTotalFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $dayManager;

    public function __construct(DayManager $dayManager)
    {
        $this->dayManager = $dayManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::SUBMIT => 'addTotalField',
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA => 'addTotalField'
        );
    }


    public function addTotalField(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $day = $event->getData();

        $total = $this->dayManager->calculateTotal($day);
        $form->add('total', TimeType::class, ['mapped' => false, 'data' => $total]);
    }
}
```

Note the use of the save function for both the `SUBMIT` and the `POST_SET_DATA` events. A good read was: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html